# Error after updating flutter through android studio

Tags: flutter

I just upgraded flutter and after that my build.grade got error, This is the message. What is the solution?

The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
✏️  Creating `android\settings_aar.gradle`...
[!] Flutter tried to create the file `android\settings_aar.gradle`, but failed.
To manually update `settings.gradle`, follow these steps:

```
1. Copy `settings.gradle` as `settings_aar.gradle`
2. Remove the following code from `settings_aar.gradle`:

    def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
    def properties = new Properties()

    assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

    def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
    assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
    apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```